# Deletar resultado com JS e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sql

tenho um script em js para deletar resultados sql com PHP e JS...

LINK

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="deletar(<?php echo $exibe['matricula']; ?>);">
```

JS

```
function deletar(matricula) {
    if (confirm("Tem certeza que deseja apagar?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "index.php?pg=associados",
            data: "&acao=deletar&matricula=" + matricula,
            success: function() {
                location.href = 'associados';
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

PHP

```
if($_GET['acao'] == "deletar"){
    $deletar = mysqli_query($conecta, "DELETE FROM socios WHERE matricula='".$_GET['matricula']."'");
}
```

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte, a coluna "matricula" ela é INT(5) para que os numeros sejam exibidos em 5 numeros (00001). Até então o código funciona bem, porém quando tento apagar resultados acima de 00010 eles não apagam.

Alguem pra me ajudar?

Comment: Número iniciados com zero são octais, deve mandar o número sem os zeros, se precisar formatar da um padding (adicionar zeros a esquerda).

Comment: Como assim Everson, não lhe entendi

Comment: Não resolveu maninho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro ponto, eu recomendo que utilize a função **[str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php)** no PHP para esse efeito de exibição, da seguinte forma

```
str_pad($matricula, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

O problema está acontecendo pois você não colocou aspas no link:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="deletar(<?php echo $exibe['matricula']; ?>);">
```

E o JavaScript interpreta o número com sendo **[octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)**

Teste no seu browser: Se executar **console.log(000010)** verá que ele retorna 8. Por isso precisa das aspas **console.log('000010')**, desse modo é interpretado como uma string.

Veja mais em:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

***"Never write a number with a leading zero (like 07).
Some JavaScript versions interpret numbers as octal if they are written with a leading zero."***

Português:

***"Nunca escreva um número com um zero inicial (como 07). Algumas versões de JavaScript interpretam os números como octal se eles estiverem escritos com um zero inicial."***

Comment: Muito bom mano, eu sabia desse caso de utilizar o str_pad mais pra visualização e não no banco, quis tentar de outra forma mas não deu certo, obrigadão pela atenção Bruno, sucesso irmão!